# Bias line using Microstrip

Tags: microwave, microstrip

I need to bias a transistor amplifier operating between 12-15GHz. I will be using a microstrip bias line to connect DC to the collector as well as the base. I came up with the following simple design shown for the bias network

[image]
[image]
[image]
From the results, I need to do a little tuning in CST to get the frequency right

Looking forwards to suggestions/improvements.

Comment: A question maybe?

Comment: @Andyaka just looking forwards for suggestions or possible improvements to the design.

Comment: Well it looks like you have the tools for the job so, unless these tools are web based or free, I'm guessing you won't get much.

Comment: Hi Hacker, small problem really with the question is that it's not a *question*, but a *request for review*, and that's simply a bit too broad to be *authoratively answered*.